# Sending POST Request from bash script

Tags: json, bash, http-post

I want to execute a `bash` script after i make a `POST` request.So far i am using `Postman` for sending the request , but i was wondering if i can somehow do it from a `bash` script as well with a `json` file as parameter.

I have looked into `curl` so far but it does not work:

**bash file**

```
curl -X POST -d req.json http://localhost:9500
```

**Json file (`req.json`)**

```
{
    "id":5,
    "name":"Dan",
    "age":33,
    "cnp":33,
    "children":100,
    "isMarried":0
}
```

I just get the error :

```
HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
```

with the trailing `HTML`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`curl` should do the job. This will send a normal POST request using the data in `req.json` as the body:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @req.json http://localhost:9500
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"message": "hello"}' http://localhost:9500
```

The elements you were missing are `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` and the `@` in the data flag. Without the `-H` flag as above `curl` will send a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which most applications won't accept if they expect JSON. The `@` in the `-d` flag informs `curl` that you are passing a file name; otherwise it uses the text itself (i.e. "req.json") as the data.

Comment: if you want to just put json in the command do it like this: 
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message": "hello "}' http://localhost:9500
`